# Compare arrays, find same elements and return index

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays (with different lengths)

The first one is (n) like:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

The second one is (n,3) like:

```
b = [[0, 1, 3],[8, 3, 9],[9, 8, 4],[0, 4, 5],[1, 7, 3],[1, 5, 7],[2, 3, 7],[4, 2, 6],[5, 4, 6],[5, 6, 7]]
```

Now I want to check every column of the second array whether it contains one of the numbers from the first array and return the index of that column if possible.

```
b[0] -> [0, 1, 3] contains 0 and 1 so I need that index (only once)
b[1] -> [8, 3, 9] does not contain any of the numbers from a, so I don't need that index
```

The result shell be an array which contains all those indexes, in this example like:

```
indexes = [0, 3, 4, 5....]
```

Is there a way to check that? Processing speed is not a matter!

Comment: How do we have `2` there in the output `indexes`? Looks like a typo and must be `3` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right! - I will try to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get a mask of matches. Now, `np.in1d` flattens the input before processing. So, we need to reshape afterwards back to `2D`, then check for any one match along each row and get the row indices of those with [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html).

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(b,a).reshape(b.shape).any(1))
```

Sample run with intermediate and final outputs for given sample -

```
In [143]: a
Out[143]: array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7])

In [144]: b
Out[144]: 
array([[0, 1, 3],
       [8, 3, 9],
       [9, 8, 4],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [1, 7, 3],
       [1, 5, 7],
       [2, 3, 7],
       [4, 2, 6],
       [5, 4, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])

In [145]: np.in1d(b,a).reshape(b.shape)
Out[145]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [146]: np.in1d(b,a).reshape(b.shape).any(1)
Out[146]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, 
                    True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [147]: np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(b,a).reshape(b.shape).any(1))
Out[147]: array([0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

List **b** is to be understood as a matrix where the sublists are *rows*, NOT *columns*.

That being said, and considering the examples you have provided, I assume that what you actually want to do is finding the matches in the rows of b. Then we would proceed as follows:

1. Check if any of the numbers within **a** match the ones contained on a given sublist of **b**.
2. Obtain an array whose elements are the indexes that identify those sublists of **b** that have, at least, one of the numbers of **a**.

I would go with standard Python 3 sintax, using a list. Then, I would convert it into an array using the numpy *asarray* function:

```
import numpy as np
def matches(a,b):
list = [] 
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[0])):
        if b[i][j] in a:
            list = list+[i]
            break
        else:
             pass
arrayIndexes = np.asarray(list)
return arrayIndexes

print(matches([0,1,2,5,6,7],
         [[0,1,3],
          [8,3,9],
          [9,8,4],
          [0,4,5],
          [1,7,3],
          [1,5,7],
          [2,3,7],
          [4,2,6],
          [5,4,6],
          [5,6,7]]))
```

And the return numpy array with the indexes would be the object called *arrayIndexes*, and would contain the following:

```
array([0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in1d`:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
b = [[0, 1, 3],[8, 3, 9],[9, 8, 4],[0, 4, 5],[1, 7, 3],[1, 5, 7],[2, 3, 7],[4, 2, 6],[5, 4, 6],[5, 6, 7]]
a, b = map(np.array, (a, b))
np.where(np.in1d(b, a).reshape(b.shape).any(axis=1))[0]
```

Comment: Isn't this basically same as the other post using `np.in1d`, as `flatnonzero` simply works on `1D` and `np.where` simply gets both `row` and `column` indices, so we get the first output there? :) OP already has the inputs as arrays. So, we don't need those mappings either, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple (but potentially large) broadcasted comparision:

```
In [14]: mask=a==b[:,:,None]
In [15]: mask.shape
Out[15]: (10, 3, 6)
In [16]: mask.any(axis=2)    # any match over elements of a
Out[16]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [17]: mask.any(axis=2).any(axis=1)   # and match on any colum
Out[17]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [18]: np.where(mask.any(axis=2).any(axis=1))
Out[18]: (array([0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32),)
```

`in1d` has several modes, depending on the relative size of the 2 inputs, but I think one does something equivalent.

```
In [26]: timeit np.where(np.any(a==b[:,:,None], axis=(1,2)))[0]
The slowest run took 4.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 µs per loop
In [27]: timeit np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(b,a).reshape(b.shape).any(1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.2 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with `list comprehension` and using `any()` like this example:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
b = [[0, 1, 3],[8, 3, 9],[9, 8, 4],[0, 4, 5],[1, 7, 3],[1, 5, 7],[2, 3, 7],[4, 2, 6],[5, 4, 6],[5, 6, 7]]

final = [k for k in range(len(b)) if any(j in b[k] for j in a)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```